# View has wrong frame when loaded from xib and shown first time

Tags: ios, objective-c, xib

I created a view to show in MapView annotation callout.
If I didn't use xib and instantiate this view with `initWithFrame`, then there is no problem.
But if I use xib, size shown on map is bigger, than is should be.

Code in view:

```
@interface CalloutContentView : UIView
@property (nonatomic) Visit *visit;
+ (id)customView;
@end 

#import "CalloutContentView.h"
@interface CalloutContentView ()
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *title;

@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UILabel *subtitle;
@property (weak, nonatomic) IBOutlet UISegmentedControl *sc;
@end
@implementation CalloutContentView

+ (id)customView
{
    CalloutContentView *customView = [[[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"CalloutContentView" owner:self options:nil] lastObject];

    if ([customView isKindOfClass:[CalloutContentView class]])
        return customView;
    else
        return nil;
}

- (id)initWithFrame:(CGRect)frame
{
    self = [super initWithFrame:frame];
    if (self) {            
//        _title = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 0, w, 18)];
        _title.font = [UIFont boldSystemFontOfSize:15.0];
        //        _title.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        _title.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.199 alpha:1.000];
        _title.numberOfLines = 1;
        _title.backgroundColor = [UIColor yellowColor];

        [self addSubview:_title];

//        _subtitle = [[UILabel alloc] initWithFrame:CGRectMake(0, 25.0, w, 14)];
        _subtitle.font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:12.0];
        _subtitle.textAlignment = NSTextAlignmentLeft;
        _subtitle.textColor = [UIColor colorWithWhite:0.239 alpha:1.000];
        _subtitle.backgroundColor = [UIColor clearColor];

        [self addSubview:_subtitle];

//        _sc = [[UISegmentedControl alloc]initWithItems:@[@"One",@"Two"]];

        _sc.frame = CGRectMake(0, self.frame.size.height - 30, w, 30);
        [_sc addTarget:self action:@selector(segmentedControlValueDidChange:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventValueChanged];
        [self addSubview:_sc];
    }
    return self;
}

@ end
```

And in MapViewController:

```
- (void)popupMapCalloutView {

    // Change this for creating your Callout View
    CalloutContentView *customView = [CalloutContentView customView];

    // CalloutContentView *customView = [[CalloutContentView alloc]initWithFrame: CGRectMake(0, 0, 10, 90)];

    // if you provide a custom view for the callout content, the title and subtitle will not be displayed
    _calloutView.contentView = customView;
    VisitAnnotationView *bottomPin = _visitAnnotationViews[_idAnn];
    bottomPin.calloutView = _calloutView;
    [_calloutView presentCalloutFromRect:bottomPin.bounds
                                  inView:bottomPin
                       constrainedToView:_mapView
                permittedArrowDirections:SMCalloutArrowDirectionAny
                                animated:YES];
}
```

That's how it look like when xib is used:
[image]

Comment: @coverback Yes, but it seems to change its scale when shown on map.

Comment: @coverback I also checked frame size after view init, and it shows the right size, as in storyboard.

Comment: Are you using autolayouts for some of the superviews?

Comment: @coverback No, I use auto layout only in CalloutContentView.

Comment: @coverback If I select annotation second time, then its frame shown as it should be... Strange behaviour.

Comment: @coverback Yes, it seems so. Have no idea how to fix it. Probably will go with the code instead of IB.

Comment: Would you please provide `customView` and `customView.superview`'s constraints? You can just `NSLog` them, it could help a lot.

Comment: @coverback I had only 3 constraints on segmentedcontrol

Comment: Still, providing view's and superview's constraints could help a lot.